# I'm unable to have margins on either side for my FlatList

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to render a FlatList in my React Native application, but am running into some issues with my styles. I want to keep 3 items per row, and have 16px left and right margin on the list (so basically the sides of the FlatList should have 16px of margin on them). On top of that, I need to maintain spacing in between each item inside the flatlist.

I've got the spacing down, but the margins on the side of my FlatList are not working. I can't seem to get even margins on both side, without pushing the list off-screen.

My code is below, and [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-paper-dsnj08?file=/src/App.js:0-1833) is a link to my code in a codesandbox.io editor.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Image,
  useWindowDimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  View
} from "react-native";

function MyCustomComponent() {
  const galleryItemGap = 8;
  const { width } = useWindowDimensions();
  const bookInfos = [
    {
      text: "Lorem Ipsum",
      color: "red"
    },
    {
      text: "Lorem Ipsum",
      color: "green"
    },
    {
      text: "Lorem Ipsum",
      color: "blue"
    },
    {
      text: "Lorem Ipsum",
      color: "yellow"
    },
    {
      text: "Lorem Ipsum",
      color: "orange"
    },
    {
      text: "Lorem Ipsum",
      color: "pink"
    }
  ];

  const galleryItemWidth = (width - galleryItemGap * 3) / 3;

  const memoizedStyles = React.useMemo(() => {
    return {
      bookContainer: {
        marginTop: galleryItemGap,
        marginLeft: galleryItemGap,
        width: galleryItemWidth,
        backgroundColor: "aqua",
        ...styles.bookContainer
      },
      book: {
        width: galleryItemWidth,
        ...styles.book
      }
    };
  }, [galleryItemGap, galleryItemWidth, styles.book, styles.bookContainer]);

  const renderItem = React.useCallback(
    ({ item }) => {
      return (
        <View key={item.id} style={memoizedStyles.bookContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: item.color }}>
            <Text>{item.text}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    },
    [memoizedStyles.book, memoizedStyles.bookContainer]
  );

  return <FlatList data={bookInfos} numColumns={3} renderItem={renderItem} />;
}

function App() {
  return <MyCustomComponent />;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bookContainer: {
    height: 180,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  book: {
    height: 180
  }
});

export default App;
```

[image: What I currently have]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea:

- Add marginHorizontal to FlatList content.
- Remove `marginLeft: galleryItemGap` and `width: galleryItemWidth` in bookContainer`
- Add marginHorizontal and `flex: 1` to middle item(index % 3 === 1) in renderItem

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-wiles-4wugdg?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks! This looks good - so if I want to increase the margin to, say 16 pixels, on each side, I just change `marginHorizontal` in `flatListContent` to 16?

Comment: @nalabof679 yep. just change it and galleryItemGap to 16.